# Integrate external jenkins pipelines to openshift

Tags: jenkins, openshift-origin

I want to integrate my existing jenkins pipelines(external server) to openshift. I have found many commands about manipulating openshift through jenkins, but what I want to achieve is in the following photo, jenkins outputs shown to openshift. Any ideas?

[Openshift jenkins integrated pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0uzB.png)

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot that you have uploaded on your answer come from this blog post https://blog.openshift.com/openshift-3-3-pipelines-deep-dive/

This blog post contain an high level description of how create an integration between openshift and Jenkins. 
Furthermore the "References" section contains additional documentation links.

Comment: Hello NoNoNo. This is correct, but I am trying to integrate an existing external jenkins server. This blog post creates a jenkins server inside the cluster. It clearly says that what I want to do is possible, but there is no additional information. This is why I am asking here. Anybody has done it? Thanks